# Can you hit two different targets with Lethal Acrobatics and deal sneak attack damage to both?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, rogue, psionics, sneak-attack

Can you hit two different targets with Lethal Acrobatics and deal sneak attack damage to both?

We came a cross this problem when one our players a Rogue/[Soulbolt](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/archetypes/dreamscarred-press/soulbolt) used Lethal Acrobatics by moving in between two foes' threatened space. Tactical map-wise, the foes were standing one square apart from each other. Our Rogue/Soulbolt tumbled through the square between them; at the end of the tumble about the rest of his movement action distance, he used the ability [Double Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/archetypes/dreamscarred-press/soulbolt#TOC-Blade-Skills) to hit the two targets that should be Flat-footed till he ends his turn.

1. Can you use Lethal Acrobatics vs. multiple targets?
2. If so are you allowed Sneak attack damage to both?

Added visual aid just in case:

[image: Example layout]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a general principle, you can apply [sneak attack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Rogue/#TOC-Sneak-Attack) damage any time the attacked target qualifies, no matter how many times you may have done so previously. Even if you are using, say, Whirlwind attack to attack a number of foes, all of them hit will take sneak attack damage, so long as they count as flat footed or are denied their Dex bonus.

However, looking at the rest of your description, I suspect you are applying [Lethal Acrobatics](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/drop-dead-studios-rogue-talents/lethal-acrobatics/) incorrectly. This talent DOES make targets flat-footed for an entire turn, and would potentially allow multiple attacks (assuming you can somehow make multiple attacks after moving, like with Double Shot). However, you only apply flat-footed to a target who's [square you tumble through](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/Acrobatics/#move-through-threatened-area), not just if you tumble past them, and not any other enemies who may be adjacent. The only way both of those targets would have been flat-footed would be if the soulbolt had tumbled through both of their squares, which would have required quite a bit of movement, and some fairly high DC acrobatics checks, or if some other method made one of the targets sneak attackable (like a flank or invisibility).

Comment: As stated in the question, the targets were standing 5ft apart (a square between them, to the left of one to the right of the other is shared) in front of the Rouge/Soulbolt. The player decided to use his Lethal Acrobatics to tumble past the two using square that they shared between them with single Acrobatics check vs the two's CMD. Or are you saying creatures cannot share a threatened space at all?

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver To benefit from Lethal Acrobatics, the attacker must tumble through a square the enemy actually *occupies* not just through a square an enemy *threatens.*

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver Hey I Can Chan has it right...you need to actually tumble through squares occupied by the enemy, which is +5 to the DC, and has other consequences on failure (falling prone...movement stopping). Plus, if a tumble is at more than half speed, the DC gets higher, and multiple threatening enemies puts the DC up by 2 again.

Comment: I finally get it. I miss took what is "threatened square" the two targets shared vs "the square the target is occupying". You guys are correct that the PC should indeed cross the very square the targets occupy. My apologies.  As far making the DC for the attempt. the PC was built for tumbling around the battle field with boots of elven kind, belt of tumbling, skill focus acrobatics, 5 ranks in Acrobatics and Acrobatic feat giving him a +22 before the roll. We suggested getting more movement speed and consider the Master Thrower class from D&D 3.5 to for more attacks or hit more targets.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not generally, no. If you have an ability to allow you to tumble
   through more than one space, then yes.  Also, if you are tumbling
   through multiple attackers who occupy the same space, then yes (ie
   Tiny opponents).
2. Once again, not generally, no.  This is simply because in order to
   get multiple attacks in a round you typically have to use a full
   round action which would preclude being able to tumble (move).  If
   you have a way around that limitation, then yes.

Sorry these are not absolute answers.  The problem with these types of questions is that there are generally no absolute answers.  The Pathfinder game is built on a small set of common rules that then have exceptions applied to them.  Spells, Feats, Special Abilities and whatnot are all just a bunch of exceptions applied to the core rules.  So, the answers to your questions are "generally no" but Feats, Spells, and whatnot can change those answers.

Comment: I think the question has been edited since this answer. You may want to update it.

Comment: Anyone able to tumble has the capability to tumble through multiple occupied squares, it would just require multiple checks, with multiple increasing DCs.